# Show the given space is uncountable.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let  $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space without any isolated point. Show that $X$ is uncountable.

As $X$ is compact Hausdorff, it is normal. then for any two distinct points $x$ and $y$, we have a continuous map $f$ from $X$ to $[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1.$
As $X$ is compact, $f(X)$  is closed and bounded in $[0,1]$. Now I want to show that $f(X)$ contains an interval by using the fact that $X$ has no isolated point. Some one Help me.

Comment: $f(X)$ need not include an interval, so you should use an alternative approach.  Also, you (or whoever posed the question originally) should add the hypothesis that $X$ is nonempty.

Comment: May be relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281332/cardinality-of-a-locally-compact-space-without-isolated-point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is via a version of the [Baire Category Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem), which states that every locally compact Hausdorff space is a Baire space, i.e. it is not the union of a countable set of nowhere dense subsets. Recall that compact implies locally compact, so $X$ is not the union of a countable set of nowhere dense subsets. But
$$X=\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}$$
and each $\{x\}$ is nowhere dense since $x$ is not an isolated point, thus $X$ must be uncountable.

Comment: You can do slightly better and prove that $|X| \geq \mathfrak{c}$. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/281332/49437).

Answer (score 3):

The idea of using normality to show that $X$ can be mapped onto the interval $[0,1]$ is a good one, but it doesn’t work: if $X=A\cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint clopen (= closed and open) sets, your function will be

$$f:X\to[0,1]:x\mapsto\begin{cases}0,&\text{if }x\in A\\1,&\text{if }x\in B\end{cases}$$

or the opposite one that takes $A$ to $1$ and $B$ to $0$: it will assume only the two values $0$ and $1$ and therefore will show only that $|X|\ge 2$, which doesn’t help.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/202054/12042) to a slightly different question uses an idea that can be modified to work here. In fact, it’s simpler in this setting. The basic idea is to start with non-empty open sets $U_0$ and $U_1$ whose closures are disjoint. Inside $U_0$ find non-empty open sets $U_{00}$ and $U_{01}$ whose closures are disjoint, and inside $U_1$ find non-empty open sets $U_{10}$ and $U_{11}$ whose closures are disjoint. In general, if $\sigma$ is any finite sequence of zeroes and ones, inside $U_\sigma$ find non-empty open sets $U_{\sigma^\frown 0}$ and $U_{\sigma^\frown 1}$ whose closures are disjoint. (Here $\sigma^\frown i$ is the finite sequence obtained by appending $i$ to $\sigma$.) The hypotheses on $X$ ensure that this is possible; why?

Now show that if $\sigma=\langle i_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is any infinite sequence of zeroes and ones, then

$$\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N}\operatorname{cl}U_{i_0i_1\dots i_k}\ne\varnothing\;,$$

and use this to show that $|X|\ge 2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$.

You may find that it helps your intuition to think of the sets $\operatorname{cl}U_\sigma$ as being like the closed intervals in the construction of the [middle-thirds Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set): $\operatorname{cl}U_0$ is like $\left[0,\frac13\right]$, $\operatorname{cl}U_1$ is like $\left[\frac23,1\right]$, $\operatorname{cl}U_{01}$ is like $\left[\frac29,\frac13\right]$, and so on.

Comment: Going further, does a compact Hausdorff space without isolated point contain a subspace homeomorphic to the Cantor space?

Comment: @PatrickR: No. For $E\subseteq(0,1)\subseteq\Bbb R$ let $\Bbb D(E)=\big([0,1]\times\{0\}\big)\cup\big(E\times\{1\}\big)$ with the lexicographic order topology. (E.g., $\Bbb D\big((0,1)\big)$ is the version of the [double arrow space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_interval) without isolated points.) Then $\Bbb D(E)$ is a compact, separable LOTS with no isolated points, and $\Bbb D(E)$ contains a copy of the Cantor set iff $(0,1)\setminus E\subseteq\Bbb R$ contains a copy of the Cantor set. In particular, $\Bbb D\big((0,1)\big)$ does not contain a copy of the Cantor set.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a wonderful example.  The part I don't see is the assertion about containing a copy of the Cantor set.  Should I ask a question about the double arrow space not containing such a copy? (or maybe you have a reference?)

Comment: @PatrickR: I don’t have a pointer to the result for general $\Bbb D(E)$, but **Proposition** $\mathbf{2.1}$ of [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864113001697) gives you a proof for the double arrow space in particular.

Comment: Thanks for the reference!

Comment: @PatrickR: My pleasure!