# Can a countably infinite compact topological space have isolated point? Can it admit a minimal subsystem?

Tags: dynamical-systems, compactness

Examples I could think of are all sequences with their limit. But is every countably infinite compact space admit atleast one isolated point?

Comment: What about $\Bbb N$ with the cofinite topology (open sets are those with finite complement)?

Comment: ...and the empty set, of course.

Comment: Instead of topological space, what if we have a metric space?

Comment: Hausdorff is enough. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431216/show-the-given-space-is-uncountable).

Comment: @DavidMitra Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X, \mathcal T)$ be a compact topological space (countable or not, it does not matter). For $x \notin X$ let $Y = X \cup \{x\}$ be a new topological space with the topology generated by $\mathcal T \cup \{ \{x\} \}$.

Then $Y$ is compact and $x$ is an isolated point in $Y$.