# Is it true that every perfect set of a compact Hausdorff space is uncountable?

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal{U})$ be a compact Hausdorff space and it has no isolated point.
Let $A\subseteq X$ is a closed and infinite set with no isolated point . Is it true that $A$ is uncountable set?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Math1000,I know that  in a complete metric space, every perfect set is uncountable. But The set of rationals with the usual subspace topology
is a countable perfect set. In recently, I study uniform spaces and I need to know that when a closed and infinite set is uncountable.

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider $X=[0,1]$, $A=\{0\}\cup\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

EDIT: However, any (non-empty) compact Hausdorff space with no isolated points is uncountable. [Show the given space is uncountable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431216/show-the-given-space-is-uncountable) And if you have a closed subset, it is also a compact Hausdorff space, so if it (is non-empty and) has no isolated points, it must be uncountable.

Comment: Thanks. What can say about $A$, if $A$ has no isolated point?

Comment: Made an edit to answer that question.

Comment: Why is $A$ perfect? It seems to me that it has isolated points...

Comment: The question was changed, see the edit in my answer.